# Minimum number of edges for neighboring groups

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working on the following problem:
Given that $G=(V,E)$ is a graph, such that $|V|=3f+1$. I'm trying to work out what the minimum number of edges is such that every subset $V' \subset V$ such that $|V'|=f+1$ has at least $f+1$ different neighbors.

I'm unsure as to how to work it out, and my gut tells me it's of order $O(f^2)$, but I can't work out how to do a formal proof of even a ballpark.

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: Take a subset $U$ of size $f+1$. What precisely is the constraint? $|\{w \in V \setminus U : \exists u\in U : (u, w) \in E\}| = f+1$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor At least $f+1$, so $|{w \in V \setminus U:\exists u \in U:(u,w) \in E}| \geq f+1$

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is $$\begin{pmatrix}                                          
f+1 \\                                                  
2
\end{pmatrix}
+f^2+f+1+\begin{pmatrix}                                          
2f \\                                                  
2
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{7f^2+f+2}{2}.$$

For a graph with this number of edges, consider any set of $f+1$ vertices. Between these vertices there can be at most $\begin{pmatrix}                                          
f+1 \\                                                  
2
\end{pmatrix}$ edges. Between the other $2f$ vertices there can be at most $\begin{pmatrix}                                          
2f \\                                                  
2
\end{pmatrix}$ edges.

Then there must be $f^2+f+1$ edges between the two sets of vertices and so the set of $f+1$ vertices has at least $f+1$ neighbours.

In the same way it is easy to see that just one fewer edge  may not work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. You've worked out the number such that less than that it is impossible? I understood the f+1 choose 2, and 2f choose 2, but I don't understand the $f^2+f+1$.  Why isn't this just f+1?

Comment: Each of the $f+1$ points could be joined to each of the same $f$ other points. Then you would only have $f$ neighbours.

Comment: Ok, so this is the number of a single group. How did you move from this single group to all subgroups? Or do I minus 1 and say this is a lower bound?

Comment: The proof above shows that with this number of edges any set of $f+1$ vertices will have $f+1$ neighbours.

Comment: I cannot see how with 1 less it wouldn't work. I mean, using 2f choose 2, I should be able to at least remove any single edge from that group of edges, no?

Comment: It might help you see what is happening in the general case if you consider $f=1$. The formula says that 5 edges are necessary. If there were only four edges then the graph could be a triangle of points $a,b,c$ and a single point $d$ joined only to $c$. Now consider the $f+1$ points, $a,b$. These have only one neighbour instead of the two you require.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your solution is such that every graph with this number of edges will adhere to the property. I'm trying to solve such that there exists a graph with this number of edges that adheres to the property. Can you suggest an edit to the question to convey this fact?

Comment: You could ask "Find a graph G=(V,E), with the minimum number of edges, such that |V|=3f+1 ... "